# Any upcoming books on Linux kernel (ver 3.0+)?

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

Do you know if new editions of ULK or R.Love's books are going to be re-released? Or maybe another book is in writings?

Latest books are based on 2.6.18 kernels, so I'm looking if anything newer is coming.

Comment: Just wondering, now that it's been 4 years since this question (and we're into v4. 0), anyone know of anything in the pipeline? or whether or not r love's 3rd edition is still sufficiently up to date for a kernel noob?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Third edition of Robert Love's Linux Kernel Development came out less than two years ago and is based on 2.6.34. I don't think there have been any substantial changes to the kernel since.
http://blog.rlove.org/2010/07/linux-kernel-development-third-edition.html

Answer (score 1):

There are two good and mostly still accurate books on the Linux kernel. I'm not aware of anyone writing a new book just now.

If you just care about higher structures, how the scheduler works and things like that, use the [Robert Love 3rd Edition](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0672329468).

If you want to know about all the various driver subsystems, choose the [Venkateswaran book](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0132396556).
Note that the book is now exactly 3 years old and is starting to show its age.

All other kernel books (including Jonathan Corbet's, Bovet/Cesati and others) are no longer worth reading: too much details have changed.

Especially anything pre 2.6.24 should be avoided because the updated timer framework that got finalized at that revision had quite a big ripple effect.

Answer (score 0):

2.6 was upgraded on 3.0 just because there was 20th anniversary of kernel. 3.0 does not have many breathtaking ideas, and most books relevant for 2.6.x are also relevant for 3.0.x

https://lwn.net/Articles/452531/

Comment: I disagree with this. Most 2.6 kernel books (exluding the already mentioned Love book and the Venkateswaran book) are horribly out of date. Especially for someone who is not already fluent in the Linux kernel, being out of date is truly confusing.